# Profile Image not getting displayed in the child pages in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a user profile image in the layout.cshtml page which is displayed in entire pages. Now the problem is that the image is showing in the master pages,but while navigating to the child pages its not showing. Please help me in this.

Login Controller to display image:

```
public FileContentResult DisplayImage(int userId)
{
    byte[] imageByteData = null;
    try
    {
        using (var db = new AdminDb())
        {
            var userImage = (from usr in db.User.AsNoTracking()
                             where usr.UserId == userId
                             select usr.UserImage).FirstOrDefault();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userImage))
            {
                imageByteData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(userImage);
                return File(imageByteData, "image/jpeg");
            }
            else
            {               
                imageByteData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/UserProfileImages/defaultimage.png")));                   
                return File(imageByteData, "image/jpeg");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return File(imageByteData, "image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

UserController for saving the path.(In this am saving the imae to an outside folder and saving the path in the db)

```
if (file.ContentLength > 0)
{
    var setting = db.Setting.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Code == OtherConstants.UserPhotoPath)
              .Select(x => new
              {
                  SettingId = x.SettingId,
                  SchemaDefinitionId = x.SchemaDefinitionId,
                  Value = x.Value
              }).FirstOrDefault();

    string path = setting.Value;
    //Getting the path + the image name
    var paths = Path.Combine(path + fileName);
    user.UserImage = paths;
    //Checking whether the uploaded file is already exists and if not exists save the details
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(paths))
    {
        file.SaveAs(paths);
    }
```

My Layout.cshtml page(Where am using the action controller)

```
<img id="imgLogin" class="lblLogin UserProfileDeatils" src="@Url.Action("DisplayImage", "Login", new { userId = Assyst.PanERP.Common.AppSession.Common.UserID })"  />
</div>
```

Comment: are your child pages using same layout pages?

Comment: Can you run the fiddler to see if there call to API ~/Login/DisplayImage?UserId=<<User id>> is failing or returning HttpResponse Status code as 200?

Comment: What i found when i checked is that only one time the layout is getting called.

Answer (score 0):

From the information given in your questions, I think problem is caused by one of two reasons

1. your child pages are using different Layout page than the one where
   you have put the profile image
2. your child pages are not using Layout page at all

You can confirm this by placing a breakpoint in the method which is returning the image (withing login controller) and check if that method is called when your child pages are loaded in the browser. If that method is not hit, then you can confirm that problem is due to one of the above mentioned reasons.

Comment: Is there anything wrong in my layout page, in case of the action control......@@ user1672994 , @@ muhammad Adeel Zahid

Comment: I think corrects Ids are not passed to the relevant method in some scenarios, so it is returning the default image instead of the one in database. please check what id is passed to the method and also check if image for that id is returned from db or not?